# Azure VM backup failed: UserErrorGuestAgentStatusUnavailable

Tags: azure

I have a azure VM. I setup the Backup in the Recovery Service vaults. Installed Windows Azure Guest Agent on VM (WindowsAzureVmAgent.2.7.1198.778.rd_art_stable.160617-1120.fre.msi), update GuestAgentStatus based on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/04/07/install-the-vm-agent-on-an-existing-azure-vm/ . Now if I check GuestAgentStatus, I can see ProvisionGuestAgent has value.

However, once I setup backup, run it, it always failed. The error message is:

```
The VM Agent is not in Running State.
```

The recommended action is:

```
This is mostly because of older version of VM agent. Please update the VM agent as mentioned in the troubleshooting guide at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=800034
```

It also has another link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-troubleshoot/

However, they do not provide solution for the same error. There is a similar error:

```
Could not communicate with the VM agent for snapshot status. - Ensure that VM has internet access. Also, update the VM agent as mentioned in the troubleshooting guide at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=800034
```

The VM agent is the latest, also, I can use its DNS RDP to the VM, there is no problem to browser website like google, etc., and no Network Security Group.

Anyone has any ideas why the backup failed? How do I check whether the VM agent is running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if restarting the VM post updating the agent is solving the issue. VM agent will be listed under services running inside a Windows machine.

Comment: what's the service name? WindowsAzureGuestAgent?

Comment: the name of the service is buried in the above documentation: "Verify that the `iaasvmprovider` service is enabled and has a startup type of automatic."